# Stop js slideshow caching amount of clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does anyone know how to stop this slideshow from 'caching' the amount of clicks through the slides? If I click the arrows 10 times then 10 slides will slide through is there a way to stop this? Or alternatively if you click the opposite arrow for it to cancel the 'cached' clicks from the other?

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/jquery-creating-a-slideshow

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) function will probably do what you are looking for. Adjust the code to the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // The "one()" function means that this action is disconnected
    // from the element once the action occurs. In other words, click
    // it twice, and the second one does nothing.
    $("#slideshow-previous").one("click", showPreviousSlide);
    $("#slideshow-next").one("click", showNextSlide);
    ...
});
```

However just doing that isn't enough. We have to hook up the event handler again after the animation is finished. Use the callback function for animate():

```
function updateContentHolder()
{
    ...
    $("#slideshow-scroller").animate({scrollLeft: scrollAmount}, 1000, function() {
        $("#slideshow-previous").one("click", showPreviousSlide);
        $("#slideshow-next").one("click", showNextSlide);
    });
}
```

---

As was pointed out in the comments this has the problem of attaching showPreviousSlide and showNextSlide multiple times to whichever button was not pressed. You can remedy this by doing just a little more work:

```
function showPreviousSlide()
{
    currentSlide--;
    updateContentHolder($(this).attr("id"), showPreviousSlide);
    updateButtons();
}

function showNextSlide()
{
    currentSlide++;
    updateContentHolder($(this).attr("id"), showNextSlide);
    updateButtons();
}

...

function updateContentHolder(id, callback)
{
    ...
    $("#slideshow-scroller").animate({scrollLeft: scrollAmount}, 1000, function() {
        $("#" + id).one("click", callback);
    });
}
```

Comment: Will this double-bind the click of whichever one you did not click on?  Since you call `one` on both but then call it again on both after only one is clicked?

Comment: Brilliant - this is exactly what I needed - this site & its members are fantastic - really appreciate all the help!

Comment: thanks for updating your post, I noticed the problem you mention, it caused the slideshow to jump the relevant amount of clicks when reversing direction. I've tried the updated answer but it stops the slider altogether. Now I've accidently found a solution, and because I'm a complete newbie I'm not sure why its helped - I added stopReverseSlide(); at the bootom of 'function showNextSlide()' & 'function showPreviousSlide()' which actually is linked to no function!, so not sure why it worked?

Answer (score 0):

You could set a flag to true whenever an arrow is clicked something like `isPending`.  Then check this whenever an arrow is clicked and if it is true, ignore the click.  Then when the animation finishes set the flag back to false.

Comment: Anyone care to explain why I got downvoted for this?  Seems pretty logical to me.  I'd be interested to know what is wrong with it.

Comment: Not a bad answer if the OP was only using pure JS.  Probably -1 because something better using jQuery already exists for this.

Comment: I'll upvote to get rid of the -1. Just because its not the best solution doesn't make it a bad one.